# How to read settings and geometric shapes from a file in Haskell for later use, with operations in between?

Tags: haskell, io, mutable, raytracing

I can write simple algorithms in Haskell, and even successfully coded a very simple graphics raytracer (spheres, planes, rectangles) as a learning tool (I wrote a more complex one in C++, for an online course). All settings for this raytracer were hardcoded as constants, be it the desired image width/height, camera position, ambient light intensity, etc. Example:

```
imageWidth = 1600
imageHeight = 900
bgColor = Color 0 0 0
maxDepth = 5
ambientIntensity = Color 0 0 0
```

However, as soon as I tried to **extend the raytracer to read these settings and the scene itself (positions of objects, lights, etc) from a file**, I hit a brick wall. Example scene file:

```
size 1600 900
output generated_image.png
ambient 0.1 0.1 0.1
triangle 0.5 1.4 2.8
triangle 0.5 2.4 3.8
sphere -5.5 -5.5 0 4
sphere +5.5 +5.5 0 4
```

**Important:** The scene file additionally includes matrix operations (translate, rotate, etc), which I should store in a stack as I read the file, as well as material definitions for the objects. If I read a sphere in a certain line, that sphere should use the material and matrix transformation that are set as of that line. Then, some more matrix transformations and material settings may or may not follow before reading another object (sphere, triangle, etc), and so on.

It seems to me that this task involves some severe data mutation. Due to Haskell's pure nature and my limited knowledge, I'm having problems with IO types and how to proceed in general, and my Internet research honestly didn't help a lot.

I know how to read the scene file using `readFile`, get each line using `lines`, separate parameters using `words` and even convert those to Ints/Floats as needed using `read`. I believe I should apply a function to each line, probably using `mapM` or `mapM_`, which should detect the used command (size, ambient, sphere, etc), and act as needed. But actions are very different for each command. While "size" only requires that I save the image width and height in values, "sphere" would require that I read values, use the currently active matrix transformation, currently active material and then store it in a list somewhere. I can't read everything and then act, or I would have to also store the order of operations and the problem would be the same... But, even in the simpler "size" case, I'm clueless about how to do this, as these are all operations that involve mutation.

Concretely:

1. How should I go about **binding a value read from a file to a name**, in order to use it later? Ex.: `imageWidth` and `imageHeight`. With only one setting in the file, I could do this by simply returning the read value from the reader function. This is not the case...
2. Should I **create a new data type named "Scene"** with named parameters (they are many), which contains all the settings to later use in the raytracer? This is how I would do it in C++, but here it pollutes the function namespace (if that is how I should call it) with all the arguments.
3. How could I achieve this mutation of values? I'm assuming I need pointers or some impure Haskell functionality, and I believe only this initial setup would require such things. Later on, when the image is generated, I should be able to access the stored values as usual, using pure functions. Is this possible? None of the settings read from the file are supposed to change in runtime, but **they involve "mutation" of data while reading**, especially in the case of materials, the stack of matrix transformations and even adding to the list of objects.

I apologize for the long question. I realize it is also rather abstract and hasn't got a "code solution". If my questions are too broad, could you recommend a resource where such a problem is tackled in a clear way? I'm feeling that I also need to learn quite a lot about Haskell before achieving this.

Many thanks.

Comment: You don't need any mutation to do this. You should parse the entire file at once, then decide what the correct interpretation of the data is. As I understand, your config file contains a sequence of "actions" (ie, draw this primitive shape, transform, etc). Then you can write a *pure* function which takes a list of actions, a scene, and produces the final scene. I would name the "settings" datatype `SceneConfig` or the like. I'm not sure how such a type would pollute the namespace. I do feel like the scope of this question is quite large (maybe break it into multiple questions?)

Comment: The configuration file defines constant values, be it the size of the image to be generated or the specification of a Sphere (position, radius). It does not say anything about tasks because the raytracer needs ALL the information contained in the scene file before even beginning. It gets worse than this, but the main problem is that I don't understand how I should read and store even constant values. I could store them all in the same Scene object if I recreate the whole Scene object from the previous one each time another value is read (recreate but set the new value).

Comment: The part where it gets harder: during file reading, I must apply and keep track of a stack of matrix transformations in the file (as well as new material definitions), so that I can apply them to an object (sphere, triangle, etc) that is read afterwards. Then, more matrix transformations or material settings may or may not be read afterwards, before reading and applying them to another object, and so on. (I updated the question to explain this a little better than before.)

Comment: The pollution I talked about is due to defining `data SceneConfig { imageWidth::Int, imageHeight::Int (...dozens more) }`, which I believe results in a function being created for each argument. In C++ I could use `scene.imageWidth` and eventually another variable `imageWidth`. In Haskell, it will result in ambiguity because of the double definition of `imageWidth`. But I can live with this, assuming I'm even right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems now this question is simply about parsing your particular file format. So I will show you how to use a commonly used parsing library, Parsec, to do it. If you are not familiar with parsec and applicative style parsing, please read [the section in RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html). This will essentially be a fully featured parser, so it is quite long.

I will repeat it once more: using mutation to do this in Haskell is simply wrong. Only a masochist would even attempt it. Please push all ideas of mutation out of your mind.

First, write datatypes to represent everything:

```
type Point3D = (Float, Float, Float)

data SceneObject 
  = Sphere Point3D Float            
  | Triangle Point3D Point3D Point3D
    deriving Show

data SceneTransform 
  = Translate Float Float Float        
  | Rotate Float Float Float           
    deriving Show
```

Notice we seperate things into *transformations* and *objects*. The distinction, in general, is that transformations are things which can be applied to objects. Then, the entire scene:

```
data SceneConfig x = SceneConfig 
  { sc_height :: Int
  , sc_width :: Int
  , sc_out :: FilePath 
  , sc_objs :: x
  } deriving Show
```

Notice the objects are a *parameter*. This is because we will first parse the data *exactly as it is found in the file*, then write a function which will transform the data to a more convenient format. We will *not* do something absurd like trying to parse files and transform the parsed data simultaneously.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards, NamedFieldPuns #-}

import Text.Parsec hiding ((<|>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Number
import Control.Applicative hiding (many)

type Parser = Parsec String ()

parseFloat :: Parser Float
parseFloat = spaces >> (sign <*> (either fromInteger id <$> decimalFloat))

parsePoint3D :: Parser Point3D
parsePoint3D = spaces >> ((,,) <$> parseFloat <*> parseFloat <*> parseFloat)
```

These are helper functions for parsing basic things. We parse points as floats separated by whitespace.

```
parseTranslate = 
  string "translate" >> Translate <$> parseFloat <*> parseFloat <*> parseFloat
```

The above is quite simple: a translate object is the string "Translate" followed by three floats.
The other possible objects look pretty much exactly the same:

```
parseRotate = 
  string "rotate"    >> Rotate <$> parseFloat <*> parseFloat <*> parseFloat

parseSphere = 
  string "sphere"    >> Sphere <$> parsePoint3D <*> parseFloat

parseTriangle = 
  string "triangle"  >> Triangle <$> parsePoint3D <*> parsePoint3D <*> parsePoint3D
```

We need a parser which parses any of these. `choice` takes a list of parsers and succeeds on the first one of them which succeeds:

```
parseObjOrTransform :: Parser (Either SceneObject SceneTransform)
parseObjOrTransform = choice $ map try $
  [ Left <$> parseSphere
  , Left <$> parseTriangle
  , Right <$> parseRotate
  , Right <$> parseTranslate
  ]
```

Now we are ready to parse the entire config:

```
parseSceneConfigWith :: Parser x -> Parser (SceneConfig x)
parseSceneConfigWith p = do 
  string "size" 
  sc_height <- spaces >> int
  sc_width  <- spaces >> int 
  char '\n'

  string "output"
  sc_out <- spaces >> many1 (noneOf "\n\t\"<>|/\\?*: ")
  char '\n'

  sc_objs <- p
  return $ SceneConfig { .. }
```

This requires that "size" and "output" are placed in the correct order. You can, of course, change this; but this way is the simplest.

Now we parse the data including objects and transformations - but again, we do not do computation on them while parsing:

```
parseSceneRaw :: Parser (SceneConfig [Either SceneObject SceneTransform])
parseSceneRaw = parseSceneConfigWith (sepEndBy parseObjOrTransform (char '\n'))
```

Now we are ready to apply transforms to objects:

```
appTr :: SceneTransform -> SceneObject -> SceneObject
appTr (Translate dx dy dz) obj = 
  case obj of
    (Sphere p0 r) -> Sphere (dp ~+~ p0) r
    (Triangle p0 p1 p2) -> Triangle (dp ~+~ p0) (dp ~+~ p1) (dp ~+~ p2) 
   where dp = (dx, dy, dz)
appTr _ _ = error "TODO"

applyTransforms :: [Either SceneObject SceneTransform] -> [SceneObject]
applyTransforms [] = []
applyTransforms (Left obj : xs) = obj : applyTransforms xs
applyTransforms (Right tf : xs) = applyTransforms (map f xs) where 
  f (Left obj) = Left $ appTr tf obj 
  f x = x
```

The logic of this function is fairly simple. It applies each transform it encounters to every subsequent object. You *could* do this with a matrix stack, but it is overkill, at least for the subset of your datatype I have implemented.

Then, for convenience, we can write a parser which performs `parseSceneRaw`, then applies the transforms:

```
parseScene :: Parser (SceneConfig [SceneObject])
parseScene = do 
  SceneConfig { sc_objs, .. } <- parseSceneRaw 
  return $ SceneConfig { sc_objs = applyTransforms sc_objs, .. }
```

Then a simple test case:

```
testFile :: String
testFile = unlines 
  ["size 1600 900"
  ,"output generated_image.png"
  ,"translate 0 1 0"
  ,"triangle 0.5 1.4 2.8 4.5 2.3 3.1 9.6 1.4 0.0"
  ,"translate 10 10 10"
  ,"sphere -5.5 -5.5 0 4"
  ,"translate -100 -100 -100"
  ,"sphere 5.5 5.5 0 4"
  ]

testMain = print (parse parseSceneRaw "" testFile) >> 
           print (parse parseScene    "" testFile)
```

Comment: Wow, now I **know** I need to learn a lot more about Haskell. :) I thank you very much your incredibly detailed answer and the time you must have spent on it! Especially since my question was probably discouraging. This was indeed very helpful. Of course, I still have a lot to understand, and then tweak. For example, commands in the file can actually be in different orders, and then there are explicit commands to push/pop matrices to/from a stack, in order to save and return to older "matrix transformation states", but you set me on the right path. Furthermore, I'll attempt no mutations :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change your file format, one low-effort option would be to create a data structure for the commands, that implements Show and Read.  Then you can use these to read the data structure from disk all at once, and to write it out again if need be.

For instance, I have a program with the following data structure declared below.  The SoundMap contains within it a list of SoundSets, and those SoundSets may each be one of the three types.  In your case you'd have a list of Commands of various types.

```
data SoundSet = 
  Synth { 
    syn_name :: String, 
    syn_keytype :: KeyType } | 
  NoteWavSet {
    nws_rootdir :: T.Text,
    nws_denominator :: Integer,
    nws_notemap :: [(Integer, T.Text, KeyType)]
  } | 
  KeyWavSet {
    kws_rootdir :: T.Text,
    kws_wavs :: [(T.Text, KeyType)]
  }  
  deriving (Show, Read)

data SoundMap = SoundMap { 
    sm_soundsets :: [(T.Text, SoundSet)],
    sm_keymaps :: [[(KeyRange, T.Text)]]
  } 
  deriving (Show, Read)
```

The data structure is read in like so:

```
  sml_str <- readFile (args !! 2) 
  let smap = read sml_str :: SoundMap in  
     <moar code>
```

And for sanity's sake, its written out with ppShow:

```
   writeFile (args !! 3) $ ppShow $ SoundMap { 
      sm_soundsets = [(wavsetname, ws)],
      sm_keymaps = [[(All, wavsetname)]] }
```

The only caveat here is that the Read parser is sensitive to syntax errors, and is not helpful in finding them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize that would be a possibility for a "normal" configuration file, but unfortunately I'm not able to change my file format, as I intend to use the same one that I used in the C++ raytracer. Furthermore, such a solution would disregard the fact that I have to do operations to data between some file lines. Even if I read the whole file to data types (including a data type for a matrix operation), to process everything afterwards, I would have to also keep track of the order of the operations, and my problem with "mutation" would remain.

Comment: I slightly updated my question, but my comments below it might also help explain this further.